# C++ vector set size in initialization list or resize

Tags: c++, c++14

Which one of the following is preferred/more efficient?

- Initialization list:

  ```cpp
  class Trial {
  private:
      std::vector<int> _vec;

  public:
      Trial(size_t length) : _vec(length) {
      }
  };
  ```
- Resize:

  ```cpp
  class Trial {
  private:
      std::vector<int> _vec;

  public:
      Trial(size_t length) {
          _vec.resize(length);
      }
  };
  ```

I've seen both in production code, but I've also heard that if you can delegate some work to the compiler, you should, so I always preferred the first one.

Is one of them better than the other?

Comment: The first one may be more canonical. The optimizer will make these two versions similar at assembly level. So the answers will be opinion based.

Comment: [Member initialization lists are generally preferred.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latter will generally first default-construct the vector, then reallocate the vector's storage to accommodate the new length (if larger than the default) (see here for [assembly code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/pt3uUU)). In contrast, there will be only one allocation for the first variant (less  [assembly code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xQiUNH)).

Note that compiler optimizations may well see through this, but there is another reason (other than avoiding premature pessimization) to prefer the first: By explicitly initializing all members in the constructor initialization list (or inline), you can have tooling that informs you when you leave something uninitialized by accident.

Comment: This, along with @Ben Jones' comment, answer my question. Thanks!